# WPF DataGridTextColumn how to bind the Foreground color in a style based on the content of the cell

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid where I have the following

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyHeader"        
                    HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ServiceStatusColumn}"
                    ElementStyle="{StaticResource ServiceStatusElementStyle}"
                    Binding="{Binding PuServiceStatus, Converter={StaticResource serviceStatusText}}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource ServiceStatusCell}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding PuServiceStatus, Converter={StaticResource serviceStatusColor}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
 </DataGridTextColumn>
```

You can see that I have a style for the DataGridCell 'ServiceStatusCell'.
I would like to put the

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding PuServiceStatus, Converter={StaticResource serviceStatusColor}}" />
```

As part of the definition of the `ServiceStatusCell` style, but I have not figured out how to do so.  Presumably, I need some type of relative binding that gets to the content of the `TextBlock` ... but after much experimentation, I have been unable to do so

Here is the definition of `ServiceStatusCell`:

```
<Style x:Key="ServiceStatusCell" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
</Style>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you see the correct text for `PuServiceStatus` and just the foreground is wrong? If yes, then maybe the `serviceStatusColor` converter has a problem. Check whether that converter returns the correct `Brush` value.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the setter on the DataGridRow worked for me. This however changes the foreground for the entire row

```
<Style x:Key="RowProcessIdAndLevel" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Level, Converter={StaticResource LevelToForeground}}"/>
</Style>
```